# deserialize soap response with repeated items but no wrapper in WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

The WCF proxy generatore generates public Meta[][] docs for a webservice respondig with repated items bu no wrapper:

```
<docs>
    <meta>
        <key>1</key>
        <value>a</value>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <key>2</key>
        <value>b</value>
    </meta>
</docs>
<docs>
    <meta>
        <key>2</key>
        <value>a</value>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <key>3</key>
        <value>b</value>
    </meta>
</docs>
```

The wsdl is defined like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="result">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="docs" nillable="true" type="tns:Doc"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Doc">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="meta" type="tns:Meta"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Meta">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

so the field docs should be an array of Doc which is an array of Meta, but the proxy generates Meta[][] instead. How can i fix this?

If I modify the generated proxy putting Met[] instead of Meta[][] I can read the response but i get only the first docs element but not the second.

Comment: A Well-Formed Xml has a single node at the root level.  The Xml specification allows for arrays at the root.  You have an array.  An easy way of creating a wrapper is to add a root :  string root = "<root>" + response string + "</root>";  The Net library serialization class does allow arrays at the root.

Comment: what I posted is just a part of the soap response which has already a root element, My problem is with the docs field which from the wsdl of the service (on which I don't have any control) should be a sequence of doc elems, while in the response is repeated without wrapping the meta elems in the doc containers

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between "a sequence" and "response is repeated"?  Both sound like arrays.  The wsdl is a schema.  A soap also has a schema the has user defined fields.  The wsdl is one of these user defined fields.

Comment: in the wsdl docs should be "a squence of doc elements" and doc should be "a seqence of meta elems". In the service responce, instead, I get a sequence of docs elems composed of meta elems. From wsdl I would expect a single element docs with inside a sequence of doc elems and inside each doc elems a sequence of meta elems

Comment: anyway I think the problem is that the WCF proxy generator doesn't generate a doc class and for docs generate a field of type "array of array of meta" instead of a type of "array of doc"

Comment: You have a soap body with an array of docs.